# Debugging PHP with Android Client

Tags: php, debugging

I've been working on an Android app where server side is running PHP.
Currently I'm doing all my debugging with traces.

Any recommendations for better debug methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a real debugger, you can use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). It supports remote debugging too.

But, simple print statements that write to a file can take you pretty far in php. Espescially with the awesomeness that is the [print_r](http://www.php.net/print_r)() and [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump)() functions.

You can also capture a chunk of output for logging via

```
ob_start();
///output stuff here
$output = ob_get_clean();
//log $output
```

Of, course, turn up `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and set a value for `error_log` after turning on `log_errors`

Comment: I'll give the xdebug a try. Thanks.